# Error 1004 when inserting lookup formula

Tags: excel, excel-2000, vba

I've got the following code to look up the date at which a value occurs in a separate sheet in Excel 2000:

```
sSheet.Range(dateColumn & pRow) = _
    "=lookup(" & valColumn & pRow & ";'" & _
    iSheet.Name & "'!" & tColumn    & firstRow & ":" & tColumn    & lastRow & ";'" & _
    iSheet.Name & "'!" & dateColumn & firstRow & ":" & dateColumn & lastRow & ")"
```

This fails with error 1004, which seems to be a complete catch-all. The real kicker is that if I insert a tick mark before the equals sign in the value, as in `"'=lookup("`, it works fine, and if I remove the tick mark manually afterwards, the formula works. So why is it refusing to be inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that VBA doesn't respect the localization settings when creating formulas - I had to use commas instead of semicolons to separate the lookup function arguments.

Comment: Haha I looked for hours because of this... How should we call it? Bug? MS Mischief?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it as a **formula**

```
sSheet.Range(dateColumn & pRow).Formula = _
"=lookup(" & valColumn & pRow & ";'" & _
iSheet.Name & "'!" & tColumn    & firstRow & ":" & tColumn    & lastRow & ";'" & _
iSheet.Name & "'!" & dateColumn & firstRow & ":" & dateColumn & lastRow & ")"
```